как сделать сокет общедоступным в python
Всем привет! Сделал мини чат на сокете, но при попытке установления общедоступного ip адреса то выходит ошибка Cannot assign requested address я работаю на Repl.it
слышал про переадресацию портов но не знаю как это сделать.
Можете подсказать как это сделать или есть другие варианты?

Поднимаешь сокет на нулях (0.0.0.0) с портом 1110 (например), узнаешь внешний IPv4 машины, на которой поднял сокет. Пробуешь подключиться по этому IPv4, указывая порт.
Не фурычит - открываешь порт на машинке. Дай бог это у тебя Linux. Мануалов в интернете куча.
Не забывай сделать проброс портов в твоем роутере.

Вот так думаю
import socket


s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
s.bind(("0.0.0.0", 123)) # 0.0.0.0 запустит сокет на всех сетевых картах, вместо 123 твой порт
s.listen(0) # вместо 0 максимальное кол-во клиентов.

Как то так. Дальше уже сам, я только подсказал, как открыть сокет.
